# DB query tools not running

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad, squirrel-sql

I have to make changes to a Struts2 application with DB Oracle XE 11.2 whose last development dates back to a year ago (and also the last access to the machine on which it resides). The connection to the DB from within the app still works perfectly but the only way to check the DB and make trial queries outside from app is the default DB (Oracle Application Express) tool accessible from the browser. With any external tool a little more professional and performing (Toad - which is the tool I was already using before the interruption -, Oracle SQL Developer, SQuirreL) I am denied the connection (even if the DB is regularly detected). What may have happened?

update:
the most comprehensive message I can get is that of squirrel:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:113)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.lambda$execute$1(OpenConnectionCommand.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: denied how ?? which error are you getting ??

Comment: 149/5000
no error message (or in some cases timeout): only the access attempt that works indefinitely: hourglass, pinwheel, sliding bar

Comment: do you have sqlplus ? If you run a sqlplus connection , if there is a timeout , you got an error. The same with Toad or with any other OCI tool

Comment: I should have an error message (in some cases: now I'm trying with Toad and the hourglass has been running for at least 7 minutes!) ... but I only have a time out

Comment: maybe there is some more information ... but I can't understand what the (probable) "concurrency" is

Comment: whe you run with toad what error code is the timeout ? is this one `Error ORA-12170: “TNS: Connect Timeout Occurred”`